# repeating and splitting list of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, split

I have a dataset of 150 rows.
I need to split the main dataframe into equal sized overlapping parts. In this case 12, but could be 24 for another data set.

Right now I just repeat this code.. but for a large dataset it takes too much time.

```
# df1 = df_all_sales.iloc[0:12].. df2 = df_all_sales.iloc[1:13].. and on and on
  df1 = pd.DataFrame(df_all_sales, columns=['time', 'sales-transaction']).iloc[0:12]
  df2 = pd.DataFrame(df_all_sales, columns=['time', 'sales-transaction']).iloc[1:13]
  df3 = pd.DataFrame(df_all_sales, columns=['time', 'sales-transaction'])iloc[2:14]
  df4 = pd.DataFrame(df_all_sales, columns=['time', 'sales-transaction']).iloc[3:15]
```

Is there a good way to simplify this or make the dfs more automatic?
It need to be easy to access the different dataframes also.

HELP! :)

Comment: Dynamically creating variable is usually bad practice, which is why it’s difficult to accomplish. There’s usually a better way to do this. For what purpose do you you need so many variables?

Comment: mainly because I run a long series of computations at each df. I can not get this to work with .rolling windows. Do you have any for the questions above?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by making the dataframes created in a dictionaries, you can change 'k' value as you want:

```
k=12
j=0
d={}
for i in range(0,len(df_all_sales)-k,k):
  d[j] = pd.DataFrame(df_all_sales, columns=['time', 'sales-transaction']).iloc[i:i+k]
  j=j+1
```

you can access it now , by d[0],d[1]... , until j or number of dataframes created.

if you want to access its elements you can use its index ,for example:

```
d[0].iloc[0]
```

else:
if you want elements from specific column : as an example

```
d[0].time # for the whole column
d[0].time.iloc[0] # for that specific element
d[0].time.loc[0:5] # for a range
```

Comment: Thanks. How can you save or access this DFs? print d2 did not work

Comment: @ScottBoston: Thanks. print(df[0]) work prints first.. print(df[1]) and so on don't work for me

Comment: suggestion - create the base dataframe once and just slice it in the loop, which saves time if the dataset is large.

Comment: @creanion how to do that ?

Comment: I saw you pasted a lot of lines like `pd.DataFrame(df_all_sales, columns=['time', 'sales-transaction']).iloc[0:12]` in the question. Everything except the `.iloc[..]` is the same, right? So put all of the identical stuff in a variable.

Comment: As a real, practical, tip, find a python tutorial about `dict` and how to use it with for loops too. It will be useful in every future Python program you write.

Comment: @creanion thanks, yes everything is the same except the iloc and numbers changing by +1. I will now look into dict tutorials :)

Comment: it'not df[0], it's d[0] it will return it to you , hope it helps

Comment: @RanA Thanks. How do i access not the whole data frame, but the individual parts?

Comment: i've edited the response , you can retest it and use the examples to access it, if answered your question don't forget to approve the answer

Comment: @RanA: Thanks very much. Looks very close to what I Need! The things that is wrong is that it uses the data like this 0-12, than 12-24 and not like 0-12 and 1-13. the rest of the code looks great and I kind of understand how to use it :)